# Pyspark: Convert streaming dataframe to regular spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I need to convert a spark streaming dataset into regular spark dataframe and then apply transformations on it in pyspark.

In scala spark, the following code works:

```
foreachBatch { (batchDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
    batchDf.createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")
    batchRawDf = batchDf.sparkSession.sql("select * from tempView")
  }
```

But createOrReplaceTempView in foreachBatch doesnt work in pyspark.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't work? What did you try? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.ss/api/pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch  Do you actually need `createOrReplaceTempView`? Why not run select() on the dataframe, not use a sql query string